# How do I remove Thunderbird as default mail client and switch it to chrome on 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, email, thunderbird

I'm wanting to change the default mail client from Mozilla Thunderbird to Google Chrome. I have Thunderbird set but it doesn't give me the option to switch to google chrome. If I open an email link in google chrome it automatically opens up gmail in chrome, but when I open a link from another application it tries to open it in Mozilla Thunderbird.

Comment: Chrome is a web browser, not an email client.

Comment: @ChanganAuto still it is possible to set the default email client to a web client. Don't immediately know how, though.

Comment: Maybe... rename /usr/bin/thunderbird to /usr/bin/thunderbird2, and then create a symlink that points /usr/bin/thunderbird to /usr/bin/google-chrome?